# Usage of Lambert Function in R

Tags: r, simulation, distribution, quantile, probability-distribution

I am doing a simulation study based on a paper. In the simulation, x(data) values are generated from the quantile function of record-based transmuted Weibull distribution which is defined as

[image]

where p is a constant (`p = 0.5`), and q is derived from `runif(2000)`, `gamma=0.5` and `theta = 0.05`.

Does anyone know how to write this Lambert function in R? Is there any library that provides this function? If so, how to use it?

Comment: [This one](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/lamW/index.html)? You didn't search a lot...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`library(sos); findFn("{lambert W}")` finds R implementations of the Lambert W function in packages: `emdbook`, `lamW`, `LambertW`, `condmixt`, `VGAM`, `pracma`, `spatstat.core` ...